# How to resize the table view cell depending upon its content inside?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use a table view cell that has the dynamic size and changes upon the content inside it. I'm using three different text fields and I want to display the text field depending upon condition (i.e. show and hide). But when I hide the bottom two text fields, the size of the cell remains the same. Here is the image to clear my question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use a UIStackView and autolayout and then hide the view yo do not want to show

Answer (score 0):

You should use Auto Layout, set table view rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension and set estimatedRowHeight